# How to fix new project empty list in Visual Studio 2012 (Web Development)?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

My "New Project" window in Visual Studio 2012 doesn't show any project template. How can i fix this?

I already tried:

1. Repair installation
2. Reinstall VS2012
3. devenv.exe /installvstemplates
4. Tools >> Import and Export Settings >> Reset all settings

...unsuccessfully...

Anyone else having the same problem?

Comment: Did you run `devenv.exe /installvstemplates` from a Visual Studio Command Prompt?

Comment: When i try to create a New Web Site shows this error: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation". Curiously, when I open an existing project and try to add a new item or project in the solution, they appear correctly.

Comment: Do you see online templates? Also, RC or RTM?

Comment: No. I can not see any templates. I'm running a version downloaded today at the Microsoft website. Windows7, 32bits.

Comment: Which is probably the RC, unless you have an MSDN subscription? what message did you get when you ran devenv.exe?

Comment: We have an MSDN subscription. No message is displayed when running Devenv.exe /installvstemplates. Two friends have installed the same version and one worked and the other did the same thing.

Comment: try to start with /log option